# IAR window layout

Tags: iar

Is there a way to save your IAR window layout? Every time I start a debug session it fills my screen 9 different windows. I would be happy with 3 and a few tabs but I have to rearrange things every time. I don't see an obvious way to save them and Google doesn't have much to say on this either.

Comment: They should be in your `*.dbgdt` file in the `settings` directory. I don't know why they would get reset every time. IAR does keep separate settings between edit mode and debug mode, so you'll need to adjust your windows when debugging, and then save the workspace.

Comment: The debug mode window layout should be saved between debug sessions (unless the IDE crashes). If it doesn't, consider reporting a bug on it.

Answer (score 0):

In folder Setting delete all files, then run IAR. It will create new files, as default, without problems.